Cohomology of a finite group with coefficients in a group ring
I’d like to show that $H^i(G,R[G])=0\forall i>0$ for any commutative ring $R$ if $G$ is finite. 
I’ve taken two approaches: The first one is to use first the resolution, connected with appropriate maps, such as $\epsilon:\sum_{i=1}^{|G|}a_is_i\to \sum a_i$, etc $$\to Z[G]\to Z\to 0$$ and then we show that $Hom(Z[G],R[G])$=$R[G]$, which is true, then applying the hom functor we get the complex $$0\to R[G]\to R[G]\to… $$ and then we take the homology of this complex, which should give us our result. The problem is this is really hefty and just a lot to write down. 
On the other hand, we have two lemmas we can use: Let $m=|G|$, if $R[G]$ contains $m$, or if $R[G]$ itself is an invective $Z[G]$ module, then we’re done. Problem is I don’t know if $R[G]$ even is a $Z[G]$ module, for arbitrary $R$.

This answer might or might not be correct so this is still open to feedback and revisions:
We first note that $Hom_G(Z[G],R[G])$ is isomorphic to $R[G]$, which is the coinduced $G$-module, then by Shapiro’s lemma we have $$H^*(G,Coind_G(R[G])=H^*(G;R[G])$$Then, we note that by lemma 6.3.4 and corollary 6.3.5 in Weibel’s book, we have $$0=H^*(G;Z[G]\otimes_ZR[G])=H^*(G;Ind_G(R[G])=H^*(G;Coind_G(R[G]))$$for every $*\neq 0$, which gives us the desired result. I’m skeptical about this though. Would be really glad if anyone told me I’m right/wrong and where I’m wrong.

This is not correct. Instead, $R[G] = \mathrm{coind}_1^G R$, hence by Shapiro's lemma $H^\ast(G;R[G])\cong H^\ast(1;R)$.
